Syntax highlighting
I tried to create a post with Java syntax highlighting. Obviously code blocks are supported, but syntax highlight hints seem to be ingnored.
Is syntax-highlighting enabled on crypto? If not, should we enable syntax highlighting? Without the hints and no language tags, the default will still be that no highlighting is performed, so the user will have to explicitly hint the language. So I don't see any reason why this would promote language based questions.
The reason that I asked is because of this question on PGP fingerprints, where I provided demo Java code.

Note that it is very possible that I missed some detail when hinting the language using the <!-- language: lang-java --> and <!-- language-all: lang-java --> hints of course.

I think this may be hindered by the same calculation that blocks MathJax from SO: Too little gain for too much extra load.

@SEJPM Could be, yes. OTOH, if it isn't used too much it should not generate too much extra load, right? Can we ask or is this meta thread automatically followed by the SE maintainers?

Relevant meta.SE thread. We probably could ask for syntax highlighting to be enabled, if we could show a significant number of posts that would benefit from it, just like we asked for MathJax support. I don't think there's any technical reason (other than page loading time) why we couldn't have both if we really truly wanted them, and could demonstrate a genuine benefit.

And yes, I do believe SE staff monitor [meta-tag:feature-request]s on all site metas, so they should see this, and maybe hopefully comment on the feasibility of the idea.

@IlmariKaronen SE devs will see this and classify it as “needs community input”, and won't touch it again. For things to move forward, we need to show that the community is in favor and cite enough examples to demonstrate the need. Once this is done, a moderator can ping SE staff to have the feature activated.

It seems to me that 3 upvotes is not enough to put this in the queue for SE devs. I notice now that I cannot get either hot or cold about that, so it was probably something that I was missing at that particular time. So if it gets on a TODO list somewhere it probably should not have top priority.

And "not have top priority" mainly means that it won't be done in my experience, unless somebody feels like doing it :P If you want to make this a priority, upvote the question!

It isn't really a queue, just a line to add in a configuration file. But that will only happen if we show support, and we haven't done that. One example isn't enough.

How many votes are required?

I really don't know, I think if you want it you should create an answer and link to a bunch of posts that would benefit from the feature. Currently, I don't care too much about it either to be honest. Show need and we'll try to get it done though.
